# Intersection of connected open subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $A,B \subset X$ open and connected. Then, in general, $A\cap B$ is not connected. But, can I say that for $x \in A \cap B$, there exists a connected open subset $U\subset A\cap B$ containing $x$?
I think this holds in Hausdorff spaces, but I'm not sure about arbitrary spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not true even in Hausdorff spaces.

Let $X$ be the union of all line segments joining $(0,2)$ to $(p,0)$ and all joining $(0,-2)$ to $(p,0)$, where $p\in \mathbb{Q}$. $X$ inheriting the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff, but $X\cap\{y<1\}$ and $X\cap\{y>-1\}$ are open connected in $X$ and their intersection is not locally connected everywhere.